# Keeping a column throughout pipe manipulations, R, dyplr

Tags: r, pipe, dplyr

I have a DF called data that has multiple columns. One of them is a column called 'swim_hours' that is a column of integers. I want to use dyplr to do some manipulations on this DF, but I also want to keep this column intact, though I am not manipulating it in any way. My code is as follows:
`trial_swim = data %>%
  group_by(penguin, date, trial, location) %>%
  summarise(swim_t = as.numeric(datetime[n()] - datetime[1])) %>%
  summarise(hours = swim_hours)`

Again, the purpose of the last line is to simply maintain my 'swim_hours' column into my new DF 'trial_swim'.

When I run this, I get the error message: Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: object 'swim_hour' not found.

Clearly 'swim_hours' is in my 'data' DF, why can't it find it?

Is there an easier way to keep a column that is not being manipulated when using dyplr and pipes??

Comment: You are looking for `mutate` not `summarise`

Comment: If you are using `group_by` I don't think is possible to keep the column intact. You can create a new version of the column aggregated in a certain way. Can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: It would be easier to help if you provided a [reproducibleexample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input data and the desired output data. Trying to use both a `summarize()` and yet still preserve row-level data seems contradictory.

Comment: If this variable has one unique integer per grouping, you could include this variable as a grouping variable.  Or make a second variable in your `summarise` call with, e.g., `unique(swim_hours)`.

Comment: I would simply try to create a copy of the column swim_hours using mutate at the top of the pipe... mutate(swim_hrs= swim_hours)%>%. Can you provide a dput of the df?